Messy UV after Tris to Quads
I've downloaded an .obj file with a texture map.
When I try to reduce faces with tris to quads the result is messy.
Is there something I can do ?
Thanks




Edit mode > select all > Face > Tris to Quads > the "last operator panel" will pop-up at the bottom left corner of the 3D viewport. In this panel try putting a check-mark against the Compare UV's and or the the Compare Seam options. (and if necessary try increasing the values in the Max Face Angle and or the Max Shape Angle).

Compare UV worked, thank you.

Side note: you kinda don't reduce face by converting triangles to quads, the triangles are still there under the hood, just not shown in your wire. It's fine for other motives, but if you thought this to be a solution to reduce polycount or make the mesh lighter: it doesn't, aside from your own eyes' convenience.

Thanks @3fingeredfrog, you are a savior
